# Lock/Unlock my PC with short cut & without password

Tags: windows-xp, shortcuts

Is there a way to configure Windows such that I can lock it on pressing certain shortcut, say <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+ <kbd>L</kbd> and unlock with same key combination, without having to type in the password?

I am reluctant to type in password each time I need to unlock it.  I know this does not look safe enough but I am willing to take the risk.

Comment: To lock normally is windowkey + L...

Comment: Very informative:)    But not what i was looking for

Comment: Do you have a password on your Windows user account?

Comment: @ bfhd  Yes i do. .......

Comment: You’ll probably need third-party software to do that.

Comment: Please do suggest any tool which does this

Comment: Please don't rollback edits.

Comment: If you do not want to use a password, why lock it at all?

Comment: @keltari - The lockless lock. People quickly catch on to toggling. I think basically, it's intended as a **boss key**.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of programs that will capture all keyboard and mouse inputs until a particular key sequence is pressed. They're usually marketed as anti-kid or anti-cat apps (e.g. to prevent a toddler or cat from causing problems by random keypresses.)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not otherwise use a Password, there might be a much simpler solution: A one-stroke password.

- WIN + L to lock the computer
- The password (-keystroke) and hit enter to unlock

While thats not secure at all, it does almost exactly what you ask for.